# Cannot Serilaise object of my class in Java

Tags: java, serialization

I am trying to serialise instances of class Employee.
But I see an exception happening and I cant figure out why
Any help would be much appreciated
Thanks in advance!!! :-)

My code can be found at this link, sorry I couldnt figure out what Stack Overflow was saying me an an error

[Find my program at GitHub here](https://github.com/AjayRengasamy/Lab-exercises/blob/master/Ex5_2.java)

I've imported necessary files too....
The stack trace is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.NotSerializableException: ex5_2.Employee
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
at ex5_2.Ex5_2.main(Ex5_2.java:130)
```

Comment: please post the stack trace of  the exception. Also have implemented the serializable interface for the class or its depended classes?

Comment: Well, please post your code into the question. And the complete problem, too.

Comment: Thank you all for helping me.
I had to implement Serializable interface.
Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to serialize objects you need that the class to serialize implements Serializable.

for example:
`class Order implements Serializable`

Comment: Thanks :-)
It worked!!
And sorry to all for a stupid question! :-(